# Правильное округление

Tags: php

Если вывести, например, `floor((0.7 + 0.1) * 10) / 10`, то выведется 0.7 вместо 0.8. Это проблема в точности чисел с плавающей точкой (спасибо, КЭП). Из-за этого пришлось написать свою функцию, которая правильно округляет в меньшую сторону:

```
 public static function fractionFloor($value, $precision = 0) {
    $round_per_value = 10 ** $precision;
    $pow_value = (string)$value * $round_per_value;
    $pos = strpos($pow_value, '.') !== false ? strpos($pow_value, '.') : strpos($pow_value, ',');
    $new_value = empty($pos) ? $pow_value : substr($pow_value, 0, $pos);
    $new_value /= $round_per_value;

    return $new_value;
}
```

Но функция работает только с положительными числами, как сделать, чтобы работала ещё с отрицательными (например, -0,123 до двух знаков должно равняться -0,13)?

Comment: А [round\(\)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php) уже не округляет?

Comment: Дополню, что у `round` есть флаги округлять 0.5 в большую или меньшую сторону. И ещё несколько режимов. Не понятно почему автор не взял `ceil`, а сразу рубанул `floor`

Comment: Например, если число меньше нуля, то округляй его в другую сторону.

Comment: @ArchDemon `ceil` округляет вверх, `floor` вниз, зачем советовать прямо противположные вещи?